# The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: The UDF class is not a proper subclass

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this issue

> The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: The UDF class is not a proper subclass of org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction

generated by this code:

```
        val probes: DataSet[Probe] = env.createInput[InputProbe](new ProbesInputFormat).map { i =>
        new Probe(
            i.rssi,
            0,
            i.macHash,
            i.deviceId,
            0,
            i.timeStamp)
    }
```

I'm using scala 2.11 on flink 1.4.0 with IDEA.
On Dev machine i have no issue and the job runs properly, while on a Flink Standalone Cluster of 3 nodes i encountered the above error.

Can you help me please ;(

**UPDATE:**

I resolved implementing a class that extends from RichMapFunction, i don't know why but seems that lambda function => are not supported properly.

Now i have a new issue:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: hk.huko.aps2.entities.Registry cannot be cast to scala.Product

Should i open a new POST?

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace please.

Comment: I resolved creating a class that extends RichMapFunction, and now the issue is:    java.lang.ClassCastException: hk.huko.aps2.entities.Registry cannot be cast to scala.Product

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. It happened because flink load my job JAR many times (classloader) and in somehow it produced that error.

The solution is to not creare a JAR including all external JARs dependencies, but to copy into flink/lib folder those libraries plus your job JAR.